# How do fish and road building cards apply to bridges?

Tags: catan, catan-traders-and-barbarians

How many fish does it take to build a bridge?

If you get a road building development/progress card how does that apply to bridges?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.catan.com/service/combinations/fishermen-catan-rivers-catan says "If you pay 6 fish, you can build a bridge".

Meanwhile, the rules for the Rivers of Catan scenario specifically state that you cannot use the "Road Building" development card to build a bridge, and that would seem to extend to any combination of expansions/scenarios that replaces the normal development cards (including the Traders & Barbarians scenario, or the Cities & Knights progress cards).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, we came up with a house rule that allows a person to build one bridge in lieu of two roads for progress/development card.

Comment: That sounds like a nifty little variant, and it doesn't sound like it would be game-breaking either.